# link to external site is prefixed with current path in Next.js

Tags: javascript, next.js

I have this link in a component with a profile/:id page in Next.js:

```
<Typography style={linkStyles} variant='body2' color='text.secondary'>
  <Link href={user.website}>
    <a target='_blank'>{user.website}</a>
  </Link>
</Typography>;
```

the current path is something like `https://localhost:3000/users/someid`

if the user website clicked is `www.test-site.com`

when clicked the path becomes `https://localhost:3000/users/www.test-site.com`

does anyone have an idea why this is happening?

Comment: The URL needs to be `//www.test-site.com`. Otherwise it's treated as a relative URL from the current location.

Comment: something like ```<Link href={`/${user.website}`}>``` now links to ```https://localhost:3000/www.test-site.com```

Comment: Or maybe just `<Link href="//{user.website}">`. I'm not familiar with next.js.

Comment: Why not just use an `<a>` without the `<Link>`? You're over-complicating things.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think NextJs's `<Link>` component handles links to external sites. You'll need to use a normal `<a>` element or use custom  redirects which can be set in the `next.config.js` file (I'm sure this is the recommended way). See that feature [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/redirects)

Answer (score 0):

@barmar has the right answer. Append the href for either an Link or a tag with `//`. Like so:

```
<Link href={`//${url}`} rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank"> {url} </Link>
```

or

```
<a href={`//${url}`} rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank"> {url} </a>
```